# partial differential equation where sum must equal zero

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am rusty on differential equations. My application requires that I characterize the function $S:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i}}}S_{j}(x)=0\mbox{ for all }i=1,\ldots,n
$$
where $S_{j}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ assigns the $j$-th component of $S(x)$ to $x$. I know one function which fulfills this constraint: $$S_{j}(x)=\left(\ln\sum{}x_{k}\right)-\ln{}x_{j}$$

Are there others?

Comment: Is this right?  When $j \ne i,$ don't we have $\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}S_j(x) = \frac{1}{x_i}?$

Comment: you mean for the example? for the example, $\sum{}x_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial{}x_{i}}S_{j}(x)=\sum_{j\neq{}i}x_{j}\frac{1}{\sum{}x_{k}}+\left(\frac{x_{i}}{\sum{}x_{k}}-\frac{x_{i}}{x_{i}}\right)=0$

Comment: Of course.  I copied it down wrong to work on it, and no matter how many times I looked at, I couldn't see my mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, saulspatz. Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: I suppose another way of putting my condition is to say that $\langle{}x,J_{i}(x)\rangle=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ where $J_{i}(x)$ is the $i$-th column of the Jacobian matrix of $S$.